# Search for a number in an array java

Tags: java, arrays, search, random

I have code that first generates the array with 100 elements, then places randomly generated numbers in each element.  I am trying to do a search for a number and if found, print out its index.  the code I have so far is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab01 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[] nums = new int[100];

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
        {
            nums[i] = (int)((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
            System.out.print(nums[i] + " , ");
        }
     System.out.println();
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     int num;
     System.out.println("What number would you like to search for?");
     num = input.nextInt();
     boolean found = false;        
     for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) 
        {
            if (num == nums[i]) 
            {              
               found = true;
               break;
            }

            if (found)
            {
                System.out.println("That number was found at index" + i);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("That number was not found.");
                break;
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

I put in the print statements to see the values, so I could verify that it was working, but it ALWAYS returns "Not found".  What am I missing here?

Comment: You cannot guarantee input number to be equal to **randomly** generated numbers.

Comment: I suggest creating a random generator: `Random random = new Random()` and use it with an upper bound: `nums[i] = random.nextInt(100) + 1`.
Aside from that, close your Scanner when you're done using it: `input.close()`.

Answer (score 3):

Try to replace this block, see the explanation in the bottom :

```
     for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) 
    {
        if (num == nums[i]) 
        {              
           found = true;
           break;
        }

        if (found)
        {
            System.out.println("That number was found at index" + i);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("That number was not found.");
            break;
        }
```

With:

```
 int i; // create this
 for ( i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)  // and remove int from for loop
    {
        if (num == nums[i]) 
        {              
           found = true;
           break;
        }
    }
        if (found)
        {
            System.out.println("That number was found at index " + i);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("That number was not found.");
        }
```

**Explanation**:
Put out of `for loop` the both `if condtion` and remove the `break` statement  from them  and create a `int i = 0` before the  `for loop` like above.

Comment: OK, when I replaced the code with a block without the break statements, I was getting the 'cannot resolve i to a variable'.  This cleared that error up and it seems to be working.  Thatnk you.

Comment: @JavaNoob see the explanation in bottom : should create a "int i = 0;"

Comment: If you initialize `i` to 0 when declared, why do it again in the beginning of the `for` loop?

Comment: @Andreas see the explanation

Comment: @Abdelhak That doesn't explain the duplicate initialization to 0. Remove `i = 0` from `for` loop, and code still runs fine. It's redundant/extraneous.

Answer (score 1):

You are breaking out of the loop after checking the first number, so if the first number doesn't match, you print "That number was not found". If the first number does match, you break without printing anything. You should only print "That number was not found" after checking all the numbers of the array.

Your `if` statement should come after the for loop, not inside it.

```
int i = 0;
for (; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (num == nums[i]) {              
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (found) {
    System.out.println("That number was found at index" + i);
} else {
    System.out.println("That number was not found.");
}
```

Comment: Can't use `i` outside the loop.

Comment: @Andreas So declare i before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] tab = {3, 2, 1, 7, 2, 1};
    int userInput, i;
    Integer index = null;
    boolean found = false;
    int counter = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    userInput = input.nextInt();

    for (i = 0; i<tab.length; i++) {
        if (tab[i] == userInput) {
            found = true;
            index = i;
            counter++;
        }
    }
    if (found == true) {
        System.out.println("Found number: " + userInput + " at index " + index + " and number is found " + counter + " times in array");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not found number: " + userInput);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Contains {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] num = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        int toFind = 3;
        boolean found = false;

        for (int n : num) {
            if (n == toFind) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(found)
            System.out.println(toFind + " is found.");
        else
            System.out.println(toFind + " is not found.");
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.